# In Outlook Interop (Meeting), what event is raised before ItemSend and after user click's send?

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

Thanks for looking.

I am working on an Outlook plugin that needs to grab any text the user has added to the body of a meeting request after the user clicks "Send".

Generally this works well with my present code which is called on the `ItemSend` event, but in some cases the user may have also used other third party add-ins that add their own text after the user click's send. In this case, I still want to isolate the user's custom text and avoid also getting text that any other third parties may have added.

Any idea what event would be most appropriate to subscribe to for this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to handle the [Send](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865379.aspx) event of Outlook items. It is fired when the user selects the Send action for an item, or when the Send method is called for the item.

If you want to be sure that add-ins didn't modified the item you need to disable all of them. There is no guarantee that you will be first.